# WordpressでDBからデータを表示させる独自プラグインで特定のユーザが閲覧できるようにしたい

Tags: wordpress

WordpressでDBからデータを表示させる独自プラグインを作成しましたが、公開前に特定のユーザに事前確認（いわゆるプレビュー機能）ができるようにしたいです。
ショートコード、プレビュー、認証等で検索をかけましたが、解決に向かうヒントは得られませんでした。
お手すきの方ございましたら、解決に向けたご支援をよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

下書きの記事を表示させる プレビュー機能を付けるなら、post_status が 'draft'の記事も表示対象になるように抽出条件を追加します。（publish:公開　draft:下書き　です。）

```
'post_status'=>array('draft','publish')
```

ただし、独自にデータを読み込んでいる場合は、テーブル:wp_postsのpoststatusを参照すると良いでしょう。
また、プレビュー表示は、getパラメータに　”?preview=true”　が付きます。

Comment: カラムを追加し、draftとpublishで分けるということですね、